Name for the quotient ring $S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $p$ and $q$ be primes and let $S$ be the multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ consisting of non-zero integers divisible by $q$ but not divisible by $p$. Is there a name for the quotient ring (ring of fractions) of $\mathbb{Z}$ by $S$?
Thanks!

What is a multiplicative subgroup? You mean subset? It doesn't contain the 1. But you can add the 1 of course.

This is not usually called the "quotient ring" (which usually denotes the quotient of a ring by an ideal). This is called the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at $S$.

The saturation of this subset is the set of numbers that are not divisible by $p$. So the localization is just $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, the ring of $p$-local numbers.
